# Simple daily Scheduled Task in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
USE msdb ;
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'Daily Reset of LogIn User Data';
GO
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @command = N'UPDATE COMMAND', 
    @retry_attempts = 5,
    @retry_interval = 5 ;
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_schedule
    @schedule_name = N'RunDaily',
    @freq_type = 4,
    @active_start_time = 000000 ;
USE msdb ;
GO
EXEC sp_attach_schedule
   @job_name =  N'Daily Reset of LogIn User Data', 
   @schedule_name = N'RunDaily';
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name =  N'Daily Reset of LogIn User Data';
GO
```

I am unable to figure out how I insert the Update command up there in the `@command`;

My command would be

```
UPDATE MyUserTable SET IsActive='N' WHERE IsActive='Y'
```

Comment: Anyway, you should also be able to add the command interactively in SSMS. Have you got SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)?

Comment: Thank you I can't get past the quote in the `@command`

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my first comment after seeing that you actually knew *where* to put the command and that wasn't the actual issue.

Comment: Well, I think VS12 actually also provides an interactive OE IDE to directly code and execute that script, I too asked a question about SSMS to learn more [without a solution up to now. Please view what I posted to help me with the issues if you had any solutions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
DECLARE @UpdateCommand NVARCHAR(200)
SET @UpdateCommand = 'UPDATE MyUserTable SET IsActive=''N'' WHERE IsActive=''Y'''

EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @command = @UpdateCommand, 
    @retry_attempts = 5,
    @retry_interval = 5 ;
```